# CSS rendering issues

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with my CSS.

Over the last few days, I've been learning about CSS Selectors and felt I was making progress. Now, I can't get past 1 issue but, I don't understand what is the causing the issue.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toa1qakm/2/)**

```
<aside>
<section>
    <article>
    <h1>Campaign Details</h1>
    <div class="table">
        <p><span>Campaign </span><span>This</span></p>
        <p><span>Campaign </span><span>That</span></p>
        <p><span>Campaign </span><span>Created on 03/09/2014</span></p>
        <p><span>Campaign </span><span>03/09/2014 11:57:41</span></p>
        <p><span>Campaign </span><span>03/09/2014 11:59:52</span></p>
        <p><span>Number</span><span>1</span></p>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
   aside section article {
        width:350px;
        float:left;
    }

    aside section :last-child{
        margin-left:10px;
    }

    aside section article:after {
        clear:both;   
        display:table;
        content: '';
    }


    .table  {
        margin:20px;
        padding:10px;
        border:solid 1px #ccc;
        background:white;
        overflow:auto;
    }


    .table p {
        clear:both;
        margin:0px;
        padding:5px;
        overflow:auto;
    }

    .table p:nth-child(1n) {
        background: #EBEBEB;
    }

    .table p:nth-child(2n) {
        background: #fff;
    }

    .table p span:nth-child(1n) {
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .table p span:nth-child(2n) {
        width:150px;    
        float:right;
        font-weight:normal;   
    }
```

As you can see from this screen

[image]

As you can see, I have additional padding but, I don't see where this padding comes from.

Regardless of the number of `<p>` tags (in the same format), the last entry has the issue. I was thinking about using a CSS selector to work out the `last-child` but this felt hacky.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: remove the `margin-left:10px;` to `aside section :last-child` - http://jsfiddle.net/toa1qakm/3/

Comment: It's caused by `aside section :last-child { margin-left: 10px; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aside section :last-child {
```

Is causing the margin:

```
margin-left: 10px;
```

That's why it has the extra 10px boost on the last item.

Comment: I needed this tag due to other (not shown tag) but, simply changing it to `margin-left:0;` resolved it and, I even understand why!!! Amazing, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use css reset sheets. they resets weird default styling so you don't have to worry about cross browser things like aside section :last-child

here is an example: http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/

Answer (score 0):

You have added a space inbetween the `element` selector and the `last-child` selector herE:

```
aside section :last-child...
```

It should be without a space (As spaces denote a new child selector

```
aside section:last-child...
```

Then you have the effect you were after.

http://jsfiddle.net/toa1qakm/4/

Honestly though, this should be made with a table as it appears to be tabular data. :)